# What "digest" argument should I provide?

Tags: node.js, npm, pbkdf2

I used to have the following code in the login and register function:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
... ...
this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
```

And I have already registered users.

Yesterday, I updated npm, and now it shows an error:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: The "digest" argument is required and must not be undefined
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:635:11)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:628:10)
    at model.UserSchema.methods.validPassword (/opt/myapp/models/Users.js:35:23)
    at /opt/myapp/config/passport.js:16:23
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/opt/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3745:16)
    at /opt/myapp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:277:21
    at /opt/myapp/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

So does anyone know what `digest` argument I should provide to `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`? I hope the registered user/password are still valid.

Comment: You can get an array of supported digest algorithms by using `require('crypto').getHashes()`

Answer (score 2):

From node.js documentation for [`crypto.pbkdf2Sync`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('secret', 'salt', 100000, 512, 'sha512');
console.log(key.toString('hex'));  // '3745e48...aa39b34'
```

You also need to specify the encoding algorithm `sha512` this is the `digest parameter` see the last argument in the documentation.

Comment: I tried `this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, "hex").digest('hex')`, it did not work.

Comment: What version of node are you using ?

Comment: `node --version` returns `v8.4.0`.

Comment: `sha512` does not work for me, whereas 'SHA1' works: `this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'SHA1').toString('hex')`